# React Native Simulator Build for Facebook App Review

Tags: ios, react-native, facebook, ios-simulator, facebook-permissions

I'm currently making a **react native application** and need the user_link permission from Facebook. To do so, I have to **submit an ios simulator build for app review.**

**I followed the instructions here** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced/ but my request got rejected for these two reasons:

1. Developer Policy 6.1 - Login
2. Developer Policy 1.9 - Build a Quality Product

**Here's what I have done so far:**

1. **Ran my .app using ios-sim launch /path/to/.app** since I did not do this previously and just directly submitted a ZIP of my DERIVEDDATA folder but
   **I encounter a "No bundle URL present." [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J2Yd.png)**, which I think is because I did not execute *npx react-native start* before hand (which I would have normally except I didn't becuase I launched the .app directly to the simulator)
2. **I have reached out to Facebook App Review Support and talked to a live agent.**
   They were very helpful and pointed out that I should also have provided the path where to find my .app in the sea of folders inside the ZIP however, **they could not provide a solution** to fix the error I have since it's most probably react-native related.

Thank you very much! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you reached out to Facebook App Review Support? Can't find a way to do it

Comment: I'm not 100% since i kinda forgot already but I remember it was somewhere within the notification of permission rejected.